# How to find Fourier transform of continuum state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, wavefunction, fourier-transform

I am working on a problem which requires me find the projection of a plane wave onto a continuum state of a Coulomb potential.

How would I go around calculating
$$I = \left\langle \psi_E \middle| k \right\rangle$$
where $|\psi_E\rangle$ is the continuum eigenstate of energy $E$ and $| k \rangle$ is a plane wave of momentum $k$?

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

I'll work in a system of units where $\hbar =1$, so that the wave-number $k$ and the momentum $p$ are equivalent, but you can easily generalise this simple argument.

It looks like what you're trying to calculate is the (complex conjugate of the) momentum-space wavefunction for the state $|\psi_E\rangle$, $\tilde{\psi}_E(k)$. If you know the position-space wavefunction $\psi_E(x)$, then:

$$\tilde{\psi}^*_E(k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi^*_E(x) e^{-ikx}\,\text{d}x.$$

Deriving this is a standard undergraduate exercise: start with the completeness relation for the position eigenbasis: $$1 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{d}x\,\, |x\rangle\langle x|,$$ so that $$\langle\psi_E|k\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{d}x\,\, \langle\psi_E|x\rangle\langle x|k\rangle.$$

By definition $$\langle\psi_E|x\rangle := \psi_E^*(x),$$ and $$\langle x|k\rangle :=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-ikx},$$ the position-space wavefunction of a plane-wave.